# Kinesis: What is the best/safe way to shutdown a worker?

Tags: java, multithreading, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-kinesis

I am using the AWS [Kinesis Client Library](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-client/blob/master/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/kinesis/clientlibrary/lib/worker/Worker.java).

I need a way to shutdown Kinesis Worker thread during deployments so, that I stop at a checkpoint and not in the middle of `processRecords()`.

I see a shutdown boolean present in `Worker.java` but it is made private.

The reason I need is that checkpointing and idempotency is critical to me and I don't want to kill the process in the middle of a batch.

[EDIT]

Thanks to @CaptainMurphy, I noticed that `Worker.java` exposes `shutdown()` method which safely shuts down the worker and the `LeaseCoordinator`. What it doesn't do is call `shutdown()` task in the `IRecordProcessor`. It abruptly terminates the `IRecordProcessor` without worrying about the state.

I do understand that Idempotency between checkpoints is not guaranteed by the KCL and the developer should make the design fault tolerant but I feel that the `IRecordProcessor` should be properly shutdown before `LeaseCoordinator` stops irrespective of that.

Comment: The public function to set the shutdown flag is defined on line 471.

Comment: public void shutdown() {
        this.shutdown = true;
    }

Comment: @CaptainMurphy : thanks. this shuts down the worker which in turn shutdown the `LeaseCoordinator`. I was hoping that the Worker would wait for the `processRecords` to finish up. Now I am planning to manually `checkpoint` the shards and then terminate. Please advice if there is a more recommended way to doing this.

Answer (score 2):

The Record Processor shutdown method does indeed get called when you call shutdown on the Worker. You can trace it back from the ShutdownTask class, which is created by the ShardConsumer class, which is closed by the Worker.

So you can checkpoint at the last received record by listening for the shutdown call, passing the  checkpointer the last sequence received function at the iteration point of your last processed value. E.g. in your overridden processRecords():

```
for(Record currRecord : records)
{
    someProcessSingleRecordMethod(currRecord)
    if(shutdown) 
    { 
        checkpointer.checkpoint(currRecord.getSequenceNumber()); 
        return; 
    } 
}
```

Where your shutdown method sets the shutdown flag to true.

Note that it's still best practice for Kinesis applications to be designed in an "at least once" fashion in the case of an ungraceful shutdown, such as instance termination. Receive and process "just once" may not be a good use case for Kinesis.

Answer (score 2):

Since version [1.7.1](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-client/releases/tag/v1.7.1) (see note below) application can request a graceful shutdown, and record processors that implement the IShutdownNotificationAware will be given a chance to checkpoint before being shutdown.

- make sure record processor implements `IShutdownNotificationAware` interface in addition to one of `IRecordProcessor` interfaces. Call checkpoint in `shutdownRequested(IRecordProcessorCheckpointer checkpointer)` method. Pay attention - `shutdown` method of IRecordProcessor should call checkpoint *only* if shutdown reason is TERMINATE
- on application shutdown initiate worker shutdown process

  ```
  Future<Void> shutdown = worker.requestShutdown();
  shutdown.get(); // wait for shutdown complete
  ```

PS: Kinesis Client before version [1.7.4](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-client/releases/tag/v1.7.4) contains race condition which prevents correct shutdown. So use version 1.7.4 or later.

Comment: In Kinesis Client 1.9.1, I don't see a requestShutdown() but I do see a startGracefulShutdown().  Perhaps it's been renamed since this answer.