# Integrate a long running service into Spring boot framework

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have already implemented a kinesis stream consumer which will run forever and I want to integrate that into spring framework for monitoring and graceful shutdown. But I found I wasn't able to stop the consumer by the http shutdown request. More specifically, only the spring web app is stopped but not the consumer. Here's what I did:

I created a main class for spring as follows:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
        application.addListeners(new ApplicationPidFileWriter("./app.pid"));
        application.run(args);
        System.out.println("I'm Here!!");
    } 
}
```

And in the entrance of consumer class, I added `@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)` to the `startConsumer` method

```
@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
public static void startConsumer() throws Exception {
    init();

    ...

    int exitCode = 0;
    try {
        worker.run(); // will run forever
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        System.err.println("Caught throwable while processing data.");
        t.printStackTrace();
        exitCode = 1;
    }
    System.exit(exitCode);
}
```

The consumer successfully started after `mvn package && java -jar myJar`, but when I use use the http shutdown to stop the program, only the spring app stops. The consumer was still running.

Any idea on how to stop the consumer? Or more generally how to integrate a long running process into spring framework? I've tried non-web choice, but that prevents me from using http requests to do monitoring.

Any suggestion will be appreciated!!!

Comment: How's the `worker` implemented? Is `run` a blocking call?

Comment: @ Roman Konoval Yeah I think it it. I'm using the Kinesis Client Library. When I only run the consumer, I'm not able to do anything until I `ctrl + c` so I believe it's a blocking call. Here's the KCL link https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-client if helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One important thing is that it is not correct to block execution in `EventListener`. You should start a thread from the event listener method and that thread will do processing for you. So you need to invoke `Worker.run` in a separate thread. Alternatively you can mark your event listener as `@Async`.

Now the problem is to stop it correctly when spring boot application is stopped.

In order to be able to react to shutdown events in spring you can implement [SmartLifecycle](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/SmartLifecycle.html#stop-java.lang.Runnable-) in your bean.

When `stop` is invoked you need to stop the `Worker`. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29859540/kinesis-what-is-the-best-safe-way-to-shutdown-a-worker) has some good options how to do that.

Make sure you invoke the `Runnable` passed to `stop` when worker shutdown is complete. For more details see `SmartLifecycle.stop` [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/SmartLifecycle.html#stop-java.lang.Runnable-).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have some questions regarding it. 1. To start a new thread from the event listener, can I directly use `@Async` keyword on that `EventListener`? 2. Can you explain a little bit more on `Make sure you invoke the Runnable passed to stop when worker shutdown is complete.`? Thanks!

Comment: `@Async` can be used. Regarding stop have a look to the answer linked. There's a way to wait till the worker stopped. After that you need to invoke the callback passed to stop (see the javadoc of that method).